# How to open installed docs

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

I have downloaded texlive-docs using ubuntu repository. How can I view/use them?

Comment: I'm honestly unfamiliar with the scenario, but doesn't this just install stuff for texdoc? What does texdoc --version give you, and did it work before you installed this package?

Comment: Open a terminal and do `texdoc source2e`, for instance. In the majority of cases `texdoc <package name>` does what's expected.

Comment: @SeanAllred I was asking how to use it. texdoc --version outputs
texdoc 0.84

Comment: by the way, in software center I see texlive-pictures-doc installed, but what is the command to view that? How do I find which texdocs are installed? I tried texdoc pictures, texdoc texlive-pictures, but nothing worked

Comment: sorry about that, I interpreted you wrong

Comment: Related [Which books can I read via texdoc?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27636/15717), [Where do I get a list of all possible texdoc's?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4358/15717) and [How to search a documentation about an tex-function in command-line way on linux?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31116/15717)

Comment: `texdoc -l <term>` will list possible alternatives if your term might have more than one possible completion.  And `man texdoc` is probably useful reading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Viewing already installed documentation**

Assuming you use GNU/Linux, you can view the documentation by typing

```
texdoc <package name>
```

into your terminal (e.g. `texdoc amsmath`).

**Viewing online documentation**

Go to http://texdoc.net/ and enter the package name in the input field. Choose the documentation that best fits your needs.

---

Regrading your question in the comments: I assume you use a Debian based GNU/Linux distribution, such as Ubuntu. You can see the texlive-packages enclosed in e.g. `texlive-pictures-doc` by entering

```
apt-cache show texlive-pictures
```

in your terminal. You will obtain the package description which lists all enlosed texlive-packages. (I omitted `-doc` as the description for that doesn't yield a list.)