# Where do I find documentation for packages in a MiKTeX installation?

Tags: miktex

Is there a systematic way to find documentation for latex packages (e.g. beamer, TikZ, amsmath) on a windows machine with a MiKTeX/TeXnicCenter installation? It seems the package user manuals (pdf files) are scattered around in different folders on my machine. Can one ask MiKTeX or TeXnicCenter to find the documentation for a specific package?

Comment: in texlive the command is `texdoc` I understand it's a bit different in miktex but there are some comments about that here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4358/where-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-possible-texdocs/4390#4390

Comment: `texdoc` works for `miktex` also.

Comment: from command prompt `texdoc <package name>` (for example, `texdoc amsmath`) should work on windows and miktex.

Comment: `texdoc` (and `mthelp`, the MikTeX version) both work directly from the search field in the Start menu I believe, in W7 at least.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The original command is `mthelp`, as noted by Torbjørn, to be used on command prompt. Later `texdoc` was introduced as alias for `mthelp`, so Harish’s hint is valid, as well. Execute `mthelp -?` (or with `texdoc`) for command line options *(Note, that MiKTeX’s `texdoc` does not understand all command line options from TeX Live’s `texdoc` and vice versa.)*

To quote Ulrike Fischer from her answer to the related question [How to force MikTeX' texdoc to open package manuals with a PDF reader rather than the DVI viewer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54474/) (read also the other answers!):

> `texdoc --view packagename` tries to open the "main" documentation file. If this file is a `pdf` it is opened in the pdf-viewer, if it is a `dvi` the dvi-viewer YAP is used.

In addition:
By simply writing `mthelp ⟨supposed-package-name⟩` it can happen that a local HTML page is produced and opened with your default browser showing the found results. This local HTML file is on my machine saved in `C:\Users\Steffen\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\mthelp\` *(in general the “UserData” root of MiKTeX, cf. the “Additional Note” in [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69483/69484)).* It does not matter here, whether I invoked the search with `mthelp` or `texdoc`.

A good example would be `mthelp dickimaw`. This will produce a HTML file with 3 results, if the Dickimaw tutorials are installed:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<head>
    <title>dickimaw</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>dickimaw - Books and tutorials from the â€œDickimaw LaTeX Seriesâ€</h1>

<p>The package provides are some of the books and tutorials that form part of the â€œDickimaw LaTeX Seriesâ€. Only the A4 PDF is included here. Other formats, such as HTML or a screen optimized PDF, are available from the package home page. Books included are: â€œLaTeX for Complete Novicesâ€: an introductory guide to LaTeX. â€œUsing LaTeX to Write a PhD Thesisâ€: a follow-on from â€œLaTeX for Complete Novicesâ€ geared towards students who want to use LaTeX to write their PhD thesis. â€œCreating a LaTeX minimal exampleâ€: describes how to create a minimal example, which can be used as a debugging aid when you encounter errors in your LaTeX documents.</p>

<p>Links:</p>

<table>
<tr><td><a href="file://C:\LaTeX\MiKTeX\doc\info\dickimaw\dickimaw-minexample.pdf">C:\LaTeX\MiKTeX\doc\info\dickimaw\dickimaw-minexample.pdf</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="file://C:\LaTeX\MiKTeX\doc\info\dickimaw\dickimaw-novices.pdf">C:\LaTeX\MiKTeX\doc\info\dickimaw\dickimaw-novices.pdf</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="file://C:\LaTeX\MiKTeX\doc\info\dickimaw\dickimaw-thesis.pdf">C:\LaTeX\MiKTeX\doc\info\dickimaw\dickimaw-thesis.pdf</td></tr>

</table>

</body>

</html>
```

But typing `mthelp --view dickimaw` will open the first result of them, i.e. `dickimaw-minexample.pdf`.

Note, that there is a certain amount of packages, where the name of main documentation is different from the package name. TikZ is a good example where you will be without success:

```
C:\Users\Steffen>mthelp tikz
Documentation for tikz could not be found.
```

You have to know that TikZ is part of of the pgf bundle and described in `pgfmanual.pdf`, so `mthelp pgfmanual` will open this file in you default PDF viewer.

I am meanwhile used to look directly in the `doc` subtree of MiKTeX. But when you use the feature of installing packages “on-the-fly”, these are found in your user profile, according to MiKTeX denomination in “UserConfig” *(cf. again “Additional Note” in [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69483/69484)).*