# What's the command to pull up a package's manual?

Tags: documentation

I am running MacTex (on my Mac, obviously) and I remember I used to use a command a lot in the Terminal to simply open up the manual for a specified package. Something like this, for example:

```
manual pgfplots
```

That isn't the command, though. I can't remember what it is. Does anyone know?

Comment: Under TeX Live, use `texdoc pgfplots`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You may also have the program `texdoctk`, which give you a nice graphical interface for browsing and searching documentation.

Comment: And when your native `texdoc` command is not available, there's always http://texdoc.net/

Comment: `texdoc <name of package>` on the command line also works in MikTeX.

Comment: @Werner looks like you got it; an answer, sir? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Offline you can use OS-independent [`texdoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/texdoc) under most distributions (including [MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169137/5764)). That is, from a command line terminal, type

```
texdoc <package name(s)>
```

`texdoc` is also available [online](http://texdoc.net).

Comment: I would add that `texdoc` works also with custom packages if their documentation is in a directory which respects the distrubution's tree structure.

Comment: Note also that `texdoc` works a lot better on TeX Live than on MikTeX (at least the last time I tested). For example, the `memoir` memoir manual is called `memman.pdf`, so on MikTeX you have to know this and type `texdoc memman`, on TeX Live an alias list is maintained, so there `texdoc memoir` would work just fine.