Theorem environment using tcolorbox (2)
This question is in continuation of this question.
Que: Following the above, I defined a style for the theorem environment using tcolorbox and keytheorems. The first theorem appeared as per my defined style. Then I wanted another box for some matter. Then I typed the second theorem.
The style of the second theorem is changed by tcolorbox or by keytheorem -- I do not know how,
My questions are:

Why does this happen? I mean what is the technical reason for this?
What is the remedy for this?
Is there an exhaustive list of all parameers/specifications/options we can give in tcbset? I have gone through the manual of tcolorbox, but could not find a list of all options/specifications (like titlerule, interior style et cetera) in one place?
Is there a manual for keytheorems package? If yes, what is the link of that?

The MWE:
\documentclass[dvipsnames,svgnames, ocgcolorlinks]{amsbook}
\usepackage{keytheorems}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\tcbset{colorful/.style={skin=enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,
frame style={upper left=blue,upper right=red,lower left=yellow,lower right=green},
interior style={white,opacity=0.5},
segmentation style={black,solid,opacity=0.2,line width=1pt}}}




\newkeytheoremstyle{tcb-thm}{
  tcolorbox={colorful,drop large lifted shadow = blue},
  headpunct={},
  notebraces={}{},
  noteseparator={: },
  notefont=\bfseries,
%  bodyfont=\normalfont,
 }


\newkeytheorem{thm}[
  name=Theorem,
  parent=section,
  style=tcb-thm
  ]

\begin{document}

\section{Some section}

\ref{foo}

\begin{thm}\label{foo}
This is a theorem using keytheorems. The \verb|\label| command works as expected.
\end{thm}



\tcbset{enhanced,colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,
colbacktitle=red!90!black}
\begin{tcolorbox}[titlerule=2mm,title=This is the title]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}



\begin{thm}
This is second theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}



"Is there an exhaustive list of all parameers/specifications/options we can give in tcbset?" Go to the index at the end of the documentation and you'll find all the keys in pink.

"Is there a manual for keytheorems package?" If you have texlive installed, run "texdoc  keytheorems" in a terminal to open the documentation

Please note that this site works best if you only ask one question per question.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz (1) Thanks for bringing the index point to my notice. (2) I have MikTeX (3) I will keep in mind to ask one question /post.

According to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169263/36296 texdoc should also work with miktex

The style is changing because you are changing it with \tcbset. Calling \tcbset will change the style for every tcolorbox in the current group, which is everything after since you've called it at the top level. If you want the options to be local to a tcolorbox you need to call them in the optional argument.

Your issue is not related to keytheorems. The problem is you are calling \tcbset{<keys>} which affects all tcolorboxes after that, which includes those defined with keytheorems. Your document is essentially equivalent to
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\tcbset{colorful/.style={skin=enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,
frame style={upper left=blue,upper right=red,lower left=yellow,lower right=green},
interior style={white,opacity=0.5},
segmentation style={black,solid,opacity=0.2,line width=1pt}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colorful,drop large lifted shadow=blue,title=Some title]
Some text
\end{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
  enhanced,
  colback=red!5!white,
  colframe=red!75!black,
  colbacktitle=red!90!black,
  }

\begin{tcolorbox}[titlerule=2mm,title=This is the title]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colorful,drop large lifted shadow=blue,title=Some title]
Some text
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}


If you want the options to stay local to a particular tcolorbox, call them in the optional argument of the environment. Better yet, define a new box with \newtcolorbox.
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{keytheorems}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\tcbset{colorful/.style={skin=enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,
frame style={upper left=blue,upper right=red,lower left=yellow,lower right=green},
interior style={white,opacity=0.5},
segmentation style={black,solid,opacity=0.2,line width=1pt}}}

\newkeytheoremstyle{tcb-thm}{
  tcolorbox={colorful,drop large lifted shadow = blue},
  headpunct={},
  notebraces={}{},
  noteseparator={: },
  notefont=\bfseries,
%  bodyfont=\normalfont,
 }

\newkeytheorem{thm}[
  name=Theorem,
  parent=section,
  style=tcb-thm
  ]

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{enhanced,colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,
colbacktitle=red!90!black,#1}
\begin{document}

\section{Some section}

\ref{foo}

\begin{thm}\label{foo}
This is a theorem using keytheorems. The \verb|\label| command works as expected.
\end{thm}

\begin{mybox}[titlerule=2mm,title=This is the title]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{mybox}

\begin{thm}
This is second theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}


